# Writing multiple-line messages with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, formatting

I want to write multiple lines in a single message.channel.send command for my discord bot.
I've successfully made a discord bot using python, and everything works so far.
However, when writing the !help command, i did like this:

```
    if message.content.startswith("!help"):
        await message.channel.send("List of Commands:")
        await message.channel.send("!chk *platform* *IGN*| checks rank of given player. (only specify platform if NOT pc.)")
        await message.channel.send("!help | shows this list")
        await message.channel.send("!updaterole OR !updaterank *IGN*| updates your role to your rank. (only PC users atm...)")
        await message.channel.send( "names and commands aren't cAsE sEnSiTivE, so both !CHK and !chk works.")
```

...So, using multiple "message.channel.send"s works, but im worried of the help messages being split in parts by other users writing to eachother at the same time.
So, can one format messages to be multiple lines? and maybe other formatting techniques, now we're at it?
I haven't been able to get much help from the discord.py documentation, but then again, i might have just overlooked it.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a discord bot print a single message on multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806056/how-do-i-make-a-discord-bot-print-a-single-message-on-multiple-lines)

Comment: @Vojko yeah, it did... sorry. pretty silly question, i overlooked the most obvious possibility:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```py
await message.channel.send("List of Commands:\n Some new line\n another new line")
```

note the `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Yes! or, well, i ended up doing it like this:

```
await mesage.channel.send("string#1" + "\n" + "string#2" + \n") #etc. etc.
```

for the clarity of it.
As for the formatting (bolding / italic / others) it might be achieveable the same way - that is, to include ** or ~~ or whatnot. i'll dig around to see if i can figure that one out myself.
Thanks!